# change dropdwon options based on other dropdown selected item (swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, dropdown

I'm having a hard time finding a simple way for this issue.

I have this code

```
@IBAction func agefromtapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    agefromdrop.show()
}
func setupAgefromDropDown() {
    agefromdrop.anchorView = ageFrombtn
    agefromdrop.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: ageFrombtn.bounds.height)
    // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
    agefromdrop.dataSource = [
        "20",
        "21",
        "22",
        "23",
        "24"
    ]
    // Action triggered on selection
    agefromdrop.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        self.ageFrombtn.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func agetotapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    agetodrop.show()
}
func setupAgeToDropDown() {
    agetodrop.anchorView = ageTobtin
    agetodrop.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: ageTobtin.bounds.height)
    // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
    agetodrop.dataSource = [
        "25",
        "26",
        "27",
        "28",
        "29",
        "30",
    ]
    // Action triggered on selection
    agetodrop.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        self.ageTobtin.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when user selects some age from `agefromdrop` I wish to have `agetodrop` to automatically shows the ages that are 5 years addition to the selected one. Example: if user selects 20, the second dropdown should show 25,26,27...

The only way I came up with is the if statement for each `from` age but that would be a long way.

[this is the dropdown Library I'm using](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be fairly straightforward to do.

Disclaimer: I am going to make a few assumptions about how you want this to be done. If these are not true, you should be able to adjust them to your project.

1. That you only want six objects in `agetodrop`'s data source at any given time
2. That the `item` in the selectionAction closure is a String

So simply, inside the closure that responds to your selection for `agefromdrop` I would do this:

```
agefromdrop.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
    self.ageFrombtn.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
    let baseNumber = Int(item)
    self.agetodrop.dataSource = [String]()
    for i in 0 ..< 6 { //you can alter this line for however many values you want
        self.agetodrop.dataSource.append(String(baseNumber + 5 + i))
    }
}
```

I am not familiar with this library, so if you need to tell the `agetodrop` menu that it needs to update after changing its content, then do that as well inside the closure.

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to make this answer more applicable for your usage, but I hope it was helpful.